# Node package open() function not working when deployed to Azure app service (Linux server)

Tags: node.js, azure

The open() function works when deployed on localhost but not on Azure app service. The function output when running locally shows that it spawns PowerShell. Whereas, when deployed to Azure app service, it spawns xdg-open but does not work.

```
 <ref *1> ChildProcess {
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961808858Z   _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961814058Z   _eventsCount: 0,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961817858Z   _maxListeners: undefined,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961821558Z   _closesNeeded: 1,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961825258Z   _closesGot: 0,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961828858Z   connected: false,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961832458Z   signalCode: null,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961836058Z   exitCode: null,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961839658Z   killed: false,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961843158Z   spawnfile: '/node_modules/open/xdg-open',
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961846858Z   _handle: Process {
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961850358Z     onexit: [Function (anonymous)],
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961854158Z     pid: 67,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961857658Z     [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961866258Z   },
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961870258Z   spawnargs: [
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961873858Z     '/node_modules/open/xdg-open',
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961877558Z     **the url that I want to open**
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961882258Z   ],
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961885759Z   pid: 67,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961889259Z   stdin: null,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961892859Z   stdout: null,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961896359Z   stderr: null,
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961899959Z   stdio: [ null, null, null ],
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961903559Z   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
2021-12-20T02:13:14.961907159Z }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: These issues occurs usually after deployment, it would be better if you provide more information in troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the node project unable to find the main file after deploying.

When we do npm init to initiate the project, we need to specify main file as it has start code. All this procedure is for local..

But Azure will not recognize this process as this should be done explicitly under web.config file.

Sample of web.config as below:

[image]

The above is one of the mentioned scenarios. You can check for more ways to get this fixed. We have a [blog](https://medium.com/@nikhilshinde57/issues-with-deploying-nodejs-application-on-azure-383e3b38e1b4) in medium.com which helped me in fixing such cases.

Comment: Hi SaiKarri-MT, thanks for your answer. The web.config file was already configured for Azure deployment and other node packages work. The problem was with the way node package open() was used in my code. I have since looked for an alternative method to better carry out the function I needed.